# Criar id's de forma dinâmica

Tags: php, jquery

Atualmente estou criando o elemento desta maneira:

```
$ss = '<input id="link" class="link[]" title="SS" type="image" src="../cancel.png"/>';
```

Meu JS, está dessa maneira:

```
$("#link").click(function(){
        alert("SIM");
});
```

No momento estou executando um alert para testar. Porém só está funcionando no primeiro input, já no segundo, não funciona. Alguém poderia me orientar como devo proceder?

Comment: Um `id` é único.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os IDs têm de ser únicos, usa classes em vez de IDs.

Se queres usar IDs tens de os diferenciar. Usando classes é mais simples:

```
$("[class='link[]']").click(function(){
        alert("SIM");
});
```

ou somente

```
$(".link").click(function(){
        alert("SIM");
});
```

se no HTML tiveres `'<input class="link" ...`

**Se quiseres mesmo usar IDs** gera numeros diferentes por exemplo na altura de criar esses links:

```
var input= 0;
// e depois cada novo input:
$ss = '<input id="link' + (input++) + '" class="link[]" title="SS" type="image" src="../cancel.png"/>';
```

e depois usas `$([id^=link])` como seletor jQuery. Nota que se esses elementos são gerados dinamicamente podes precisar de delegar o evento.

Comment: Sergio, 

'$(".link").click(function(){' não funcionou, somente com 

'$("[class='link[]']").click(function(){'. 

Obrigado

Comment: @FelipeFM exato, como eu disse na resposta usa `$(".link")` __se__ no HTML tiveres `'<input class="link" ...`

Comment: Compreendi, e para pegar seu value, seria o mesmo raciocínio? Teria que pegar via class também?

Comment: @FelipeFM dentro dessa função podes usar nativo: `this.value` ou com jQuery `$(this).val();`

Comment: Perfeito Sergio! Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque o **seletor por id** do jQuery internamente usa `document.getElementById`, retornando assim o primeiro e/ou único elemento corresponde a tal id.

Se você quer uma lista, tem de usar o **seletor de classe**.

Exemplo:

```
$ss = '<input class="link" class="link[]" title="SS" type="image" src="../cancel.png"/>';

$('.link').click(function(){
    console.log(this);
});
```